# How to make nlargest function give error if argument is greater than length

Tags: python, pandas

I want `nlargest` function to give an error, if `n` is greater than the length of series.
Is there any way to do this

```
pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]).nlargest(10)
```

As you can see that length of series is less than 10, so I want an error here. What should I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just write a function for it:

```py
def custom_nlargest(series, n):
    if n > len(series):
        raise ValueError("n is greater than series length!")
    else:
        return series.nlargest(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping it in a function:

```
def my_nlargest(series, n):
    if len(series) < n: return 'error message'
    return series.nlargest(n)
```